# How to Convert url requests to Dtos in ServiceStack Typescript Client

Tags: servicestack

Is it possible to convert urls into Dtos in the Service Stack typescript json client? I see these extensions on the c# client but not in typescript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ServiceStack's [TypeScript Request DTOs](http://docs.servicestack.net/typescript-add-servicestack-reference) don't have access to the `[Route]` attribute metadata so they only [generate pre-defined URLs](http://docs.servicestack.net/routing#pre-defined-routes) within the Service Client but you can use the [createUrl helper](http://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v5.0.0#angular-5-http-client) to be able to generate a URL by passing in the route definition, e.g:

```
import { createUrl } from '@servicestack/client';

let url = createUrl('/hello/{Name}', { name, foo:1 });
```

Which will generate that populates the route path and appends any additional object args to the queryString, e.g:

```
/hello/name?foo=1
```